# How to properly analyse this simple circuit?

Tags: analysis

I often get awfully confused when presented with circuits like this, and can spend around 20 mins looking at it trying to figure out exactly whats happening.

So the way i find the voltage across 100M resistor is:

1/ Notice there is a potential diff of 5V between 10V and 5V supplies

2/ Most of the current flow will be through the 1k resistors

3/ because there are two 1k resistors there should be 2.5V at dropped across R1

4/ Therefore 7.5V will be dropped across R3 as it is 5V below the 5V supply

Is this a correct line of thinking? Is there a simpler way to analyse this?

[image: Simple Circuit]

Comment: Given the difference in magnitude between R1, R2 and then R3 (which is MUCH larger in value), your analysis is good enough. A problem would arise if, for example, R3 itself was much closer in value to R1 and R2. If R3 were also 1k, then there would be 5 V at the shared node and not 7.4999625 volts.

Comment: It's not "correct" in the mathematical sense but noting that R3/R1 is 100000 it's what I'd do too. You can then model R1-R2 as a 500R resistor connected to 7.5V (Thevenin equivalent) and calculate the actual voltage across R3 if you want to be pedantic. Then compare that change with the effect of a 1% tolerance in R1...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a linear circuit and you can apply the principle of superposition. For a linear circuit with multiple sources, you analyze the circuit as a sum of the output response for each source individually, with all others disabled. For a voltage source, disabling means set it to 0V, a grounded node. For a current source, disabling means to set it to an open circuit, a floating node.

In this case, analyze the circuit with V1 = 5V and V2=0V. Vout1 = 5V * (R2||R3)/(R1+(R2||R3)
Because R3 is so big compared to R2, Vout1 will be 2.5V.

Next, analyze the circuit with V1=0V and V2 = 10V. Vout2 = 10V *(R1||R3)/(R2+(R1||R3) = 5V

Vout total = Vout1 + Vout2 = 7.5V

Comment: thank u , i think this makes the most sense to me!